# How to make Request Tracker use an external SMTP mail server?

Tags: smtp, request-tracker

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and by following [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Request%20Tracker) I have made RT run well in everything except for sending outbound emails. The difference is, I need to make RT use an external, existing mail server. The mail server is accessible via SMTP with authentication so I am looking for a place to insert the username and password, but nothing like that seems to exist.

The closest thing that I found by googling is that I need to setup ssmtp or msmtp and use it to forward my outbound emails to the mail server (sorry I lost the link). Is that true? Are there any (perhaps better) other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting RT to use an external SMTP server is easy, except for the authentication part.  As you have surmised, to use authenticated SMTP you need the support of another program, either a properly configued system MTA like Postfix or Sendmail or a minimal MTA like msmtp.  This question has been asked (and answered) frequently on the RT mailing lists:

- http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/rt/users/94423
- http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/rt/users/90745

Comment: This is exactly what I'm afraid of, really no such option within RT?

Comment: Evidence suggests that this is the case.  Where we work we have the RT server on a network that is not required to authenticate to the mail server.  In general, I think many software authors assume it is the system's job to handle mail delivery appropriately (and they design their applications accordingly).

Comment: Mind you, RT's Perl code is pretty clean. I've never looked at the mailer stuff, but you could probably make it work without too much effort (it's probably already using a standard Perl module for SMTP).

Comment: I have been playing around with ssmtp and msmtp, now how can I make RT use msmtp? Do I just change `$MailCommand` to msmtp?

Comment: Read through http://wiki.bestpractical.com/view/RT_Config...it looks like you would set MailCommand to sendmailpipe (or sendmail), and then set SendmailPath and SendmailArguments to whatever is appropriate for msmtp.  Possible msmtp provides a sendmail-compatible command line; I've never used it myself.  There may be some examples of configuring RT with msmtp on The Google.

Answer (score 0):

Install one of them:

1. https://wiki.debian.org/msmtp
2. https://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP

It will create a symlink from sendmail to msmtp, which will forward to any SMTP server you configure. Then configure RT to use sendmail.